CumulusCI keyword for Upserting Data in case of External ID
Do we have any CumulusCI keyword for Upserting Data in case of External ID like we have for Insert, Get update and delete in CumulusCI Robot Framework Keywords
Can we use existing keyword for Upserting Data?

CumulusCI's Robot Framework does not have a specific keyword explicitly named for "upsert" operations based on external IDs directly out of the box. There is way around where you can achieve the upsert functionality by using a combination of the available CumulusCI Robot Framework keywords and some custom logic

Thank you @TSCAmerica.com I am getting the Record ID from using SOQL query and than passing the ID and Inserting the record.
